# How do I skip the confirmation after creating a reminder in Google Now using voice?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-6, google-now

Before, when I'd activate Google Now with "Ok Google" to create a reminder, it would just create it right away.

Now, it asks me for confirmation to save and I have to say "yes".  How do I revert it back to the old way so that it just automatically saves.

Samsung Galaxy S6 (Unlocked)
Android 6.0.1

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem :(